# WPML change languages

Tags: wordpress, web, elementor, wpml

I use WPML to create a bilingual website. The website is built with Elementor. I've translated all the pages in both English and Hong Kong Chinese. However, when I edit the Elementor content while being in the English version, the corresponding content in the Hong Kong Chinese version also changes to English, including page names. But when I make changes in the Hong Kong Chinese version, it doesn't affect the English version. Can someone provide me with a solution or is this due to incorrect setup on my part? I need assistance and thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tVD3.jpg)

I had to resort to opening two Elementor tabs, making the changes in the English version, and then saving it again within the Hong Kong tab to preserve the initial setup. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome! This question is much better suited for WPML support forums. There are way too many variables using WPML to consider and you can give them access to your site to check. And this is not a code issue.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! i do curious, does any of the entire steps involve writing codes?

Comment: Open a ticket at WPML support where they will fix it for you or give you help how to resolve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.